# How to display an image from my desktop in java?

Tags: java

I'm using BlueJ, and I want to display an image from my desktop in a window using a java program. I know how to use java.swing and JFrame, but how can I upload it from my desktop or a folder?

I want it to look like:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class example extends JFrame {
    public example () {
        super("Blahblahblah");

        image = getImage("image");
        add(image);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by take a look at [Reading images using ImageIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html).

Basically, you load the image...

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("/path/to/image"));
```

Then apply it to a `JLabel`...

```
JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img));
```

Then a the label to the frame...

```
add(label);
```